# How to block TypeScript class property or method multi-level inheritance?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

Here is the next JavaScript class structure:

```
// data.service.ts
export class DataService {
   public url = environment.url;

   constructor(
       private uri: string,
       private httpClient: HttpClient,
   ) { }

   getAll() {}

   getOne(id: number) {}

   create(data: any) {}

   // etc...
}
```

Next is the general data model what can use the DataService's methods to communicate the server:

```
// Model.model.ts
import './data.service';

export class Model extends DataService {
    all() {}

    get() {
        // parse and make some basic validation on the
        // DataService.getOne() JSON result
    }

    // etc...
}
```

And finally I create a specific data model based on Model.model.ts:

```
// User.model.ts
import './Model.model.ts';

export class User extends Model {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    email: string;

    init() {
        // make specific validation on Model.get() result
    }
}
```

If I use the User class in my code, I can call the DataService's getAll() function directly if I want. But this is not a good thing, because in this case I miss the built-in validations.

How can I block the method inheritance on a class?

I'm looking for something like PHP's `static` method. The child class can use the methods, but his child can't.

I want something like this:

```
const dataService = new DataService();
dataService.getAll(); // void

const model = new Model();
model.getAll(); // undefined
model.all();    // void

const user = new User();
user.getAll();  // undefined
user.all();     // void
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You need `private` and `protected`, I guess.

Comment: Conceptually, a Model ***isn't*** a DataService and modelling it as such seems quite wrong to me. Perhaps one might require the other, but they should not be the same thing.

Comment: It isn't but the Model can have get() method what can fetch datas from the server, and then can initialize itself. In this case I can use `user.get(1)` to fetch datas, and initialize they into the User model. And of course the user.get() method expect a JSON from API what looks like an User model, but maybe conains `0`, `null` or `''` values. The user.init() can handle these and finally I get a valid User model. And of course I user many models to clients, products, documents, casefiles, and so on... Every model need a .get() method and a specific .init() method to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent it ***to be built*** when you call it by adding `private` keyword to the function `private getAll() {}`. But `private` is a TypeScript feature, not Javascript, so if you force it to be built, it is still callable. There'll be no way to totally prevent it this moment.

So if you want it to be prevented in `TypeScript`, just add `private` keyword there. But it is not buildable, not return undefined as you expect. Otherwise, just replace the function with an undefined-returned function on children classes

Answer (score 0):

With your code as shown and use case as stated, the only way to get the behavior you want is not to make `Model` extend `DataService` at all.  There is a [subsitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which says that if `Model extends DataService`, then someone should be able to treat a `Model` instance exactly as they would treat a `DataService` instance.  Indeed, if a `Model` is a special type of `DataService`, and someone asks for a `DataService` instance, you should be able to give them a `Model`.  It's no fair for you to tell them that they can't call the `getAll()` method on it.  So the inheritance tree can't work the way you have it.  Instead you could do something like this:

```
// ultimate parent class of both DataService and Model/User 
class BaseDataService {
  getOne(id: number) { }
  create(data: any) { }
  // etc...
}

// subclass with getAll()
class DataService extends BaseDataService {
  getAll() {}
}


// subclass without getAll()
class Model extends BaseDataService {
  all() { }
  get() { }
  // etc...
}

class User extends Model {
  id!: number;
  name!: string;
  email!: string;
  init() { }
}

const dataService = new DataService();
dataService.getAll(); // void

const model = new Model();
model.getAll(); // error
model.all();    // okay

const user = new User();
user.getAll();  // error
user.all();     // okay
```

That works exactly as you've specified.  Perfect, right?

---

Well, I get the sinking feeling that you will try this and get upset that you cannot call `this.getAll()` inside the *implementation* of `Model` or `User`... probably inside the suspiciously-empty body of the `all()` method in `Model`.  And already I'm getting the urge to defensively point to the [Minimum, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) article, since the question *as stated* doesn't seem to require this.

If you do require that, you still can't break the substitution principle.  Instead I'd suggest making `getAll()` a [`protected`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#understanding-protected) method, and expose an `all()` method on `DataService`:

```
class DataService {
  getOne(id: number) { }
  create(data: any) { }
  protected getAll() { }
  all() { 
    this.getAll();
  }
  // etc...
}

class Model extends DataService {
  all() {
    this.getAll();
  }
  get() { }
  // etc...
}

class User extends Model {
  id!: number;
  name!: string;
  email!: string;
  init() { }
}

const dataService = new DataService();
dataService.getAll(); // error
dataService.all(); // okay

const model = new Model();
model.getAll(); // error
model.all();    // okay

const user = new User();
user.getAll();  // error
user.all();     // okay
```

and live with the fact that `getAll()` is a purely internal method never meant to see the light of day.

Okay, hope one of those helps; good luck!